# TCPClient NetworkStream Write Exception: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp, c++-cli, tcpclient

I created simple application that sends small data over TCP. I could not manage to send data. Connection is established but the on Write procedure it throws exception: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

Communication initialization:

```
CommunicationClient = gcnew TcpClient();
CommunicationClient->Connect(ServerAddress, PortRead);
CommunicationClient->ReceiveTimeout = TimeOut;
```

Data send:

```
NetworkStream^ NetStream = CommunicationClient->GetStream();
NetStream->Write(PacketDataToSend, 0, PacketDataToSend->Length);
```

I tried to turn off firewall, restart machine, tried to compile in debug/release mode, run on other machine.

Comment: I assume you also have some server code. It would be helpful to post it too.

Comment: I don't I am connecting to some Siemens PLC with Step7 on it. When checked in WireShark, no packets were even sent, so there was some problem on my side. Thought that was some problem with firewall but problem persisted even after turning it off.

Comment: There is a small software called "hercules" (http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_de.html), that provides a TCP client, a TCP server, an UDP client, RS232. I use it frequently for tests on devices that connect via TCP or UDP, and used it to test my own TCP client program.

Comment: Furthermore I recommend "Sysinternals Suite" and especially the small program TCPView from that suite.